# 502 Bad Gateway, I messed up users and groups permissions on digitalocean ubuntu for django deployment

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

1. I have created a droplet, an ubuntu 18.04 server on digitalocen successfully.
2. Followed the install digitalocean's guide and ran the gunicorn,nginx, django etc. and ran the website successfully on the browser using my ip address i.e. firewalls, gunicorn and nginx and everything were configured correctly.
3. During the testing while uploading the images to the media folder I got an error  "permissions denied" (POST error).
4. Found somewhere the below code on google and thought it solves the permissions related problem: https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/55551/django-errno-13-permission-denied-39-var-www-media-animals-user-uploads-39

```
sudo groupadd varwwwusers
sudo adduser www-data varwwwusers
sudo chgrp -R varwwwusers /var/www/
sudo chmod -R 760 /var/www/
```

**But the above code messed up everything and ran into "502 Bad Gateway".**

I am not very familiar with Linux deployments. Can someone help me investigating and resolving this issue. I think I have messed up the users, groups permissions.

How can I get this resolved OR how can I revert what I did OR is there any activity logs I can see and investigate.

I have checked the error.log and able to see 
' connect() to unix:/run/gunicorn.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream'

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that by running `sudo chmod -R 760 /var/www/` you have forbidden non-ownesrs of the folder to read, write and execute files form that directory. Then, since uwsgi processes does not belong to the www-data group (usually), uwsgi connection was refused.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to run `sudo chmod -R 766 /var/www/` - this will grant writing and readind priveleges to anyone (`chmod -R 764` should also work and is safer - it allows only reading files for non-owners). Alternatively, you may find out the name of the user running uwsgi and grant him permissions for reading files form the directory. See `chmod` manual (or google it) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Only in case of 777, I am able to run Gunicorn. I have tried with 764 and 766 but that didn't help. I've reverted the permissions though. I don't think it's a good idea to allow the user with 777. Please suggest.

Comment: You may try using 'chown' to set your user on the server as the owner of '/var/www/' (or another directory used to run gunicorn): 'chown -R user directory'. In this case the first 7 in 766 should allow you to run gunicorn. Alternatively, you can simply add your user to the _varwwwusers_ group and grant that group 7 permison. In this case chmod -R 770 should work. Does any of these helps?

Comment: I will try and let you know about this. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Thanks Ivan K. for the suggestions. I am a newbie in linux/unix.
0755 allowed me to get my website back but didn't allow me to post image and shown the original error permissions denied in media folder
0764 - didn't allow to run gunicorn
0766 - didn't allow to run gunicorn
0770 - didn't allow to run gunicorn
0774 - didn't allow to run gunicorn
0775 - allowed me to run gunicorn and allowed to post/save the data/image as well
I think the directory which owns the project under /home/myuser/.blabla./ my user needs at least 77 for owner and group and at least read/write for all others.

Comment: 1. Am I getting it correct? Please suggest. 
2. Is this a safe/secure permission? 
3. Everything is running fine now but I need to understand How can I confirm if I meesed up anything with gunicorn/nginx permissions/settings. I am assuming that configs are fine that's why my system is up and running.


Thanks very much.

Comment: Assuming you are the only user that has access to the server, yours settings are quite ok. As the server is runing and operating how it should, gunicorn and nginx have all permisions they need. However, I suggest you reading/watching a manual/tutorial on permissions on unix (just google it). This is fairly easy and will considerably help you in future. When yo understand them, you will be able to set up safer permissions. However, what you have now should work quite well (I see no real risk).

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are a champ!!!  I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: If the problem is solved, please, mark my answer as the solution.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the support.